# Disabling textboxes on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, html

I have a login form in one div which is initially hidden and when clicked on "Login" it is visible.
This login form is in **Master Page** and has client side HTML5 validations for email id and pwd.

I have one child page with ajax update panel which has one button "Add to Cart". But due to this validation in master page login form i m not able to do **postback** on **"Add to Cart"** button click.

For avoiding such thing I m trying to disable all text boxes in that login form(which is in master page) at page load:
**C#:**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "Javascript2", "javascript:DisablePopUpTxt();", true);
```

**JS:**

```
function DisablePopUpTxt() {

    document.getElementById("txtCustEmailID").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("txtCustPwd").disabled = true;
}
```

but above code not working and I am not able to do any **post back** on any of the child page.
Plz give me any solution.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Why dont you disable the input boxes in the html code itself. <input type="text" id="txtCustEmailId" disabled>

Comment: @T0X1C—because then if the user agent has scripting disabled or the script to disable them fails, the inputs will always be disabled.

Comment: Are you running the code *after* the page loads, i.e. after the elements exist?

Comment: @TOX1C: i disabled the textbox as u said:  <input id="txtRCustFName" name="txtRCustFName" type="text" required disabled /> but i m not able to enable it using js: document.getElementById("txtRCustFName").disabled = false

Answer (score 0):

I think setting `CauseValidation=false` on the particular link or button might solve your error for more understanding you can check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using different validation groups for master and child page.  Just select each control in master page including button and set ValidationGroup property.